# Markdown how to change the default Text size Android Markwon

Tags: android, kotlin, markdown, android-theme, markwon

Where can I set the configuration to set a custom font and text size for "regular text" while rendering Markdown with the Markwon dependency?

Setting custom multipliers for the headings and setting the codeBlock text sizes don't work. Neither works setting the `<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/mytextappearance</item>` in the application theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind; I found it:

When building the Markwon instance you do:

```kotlin
Markwon
    .builder(context)
    .usePlugin(object : AbstractMarkwonPlugin(){
          override fun configureSpansFactory(builder: MarkwonSpansFactory.Builder) {
               super.configureSpansFactory(builder)
               builder.setFactory(Text::class.java) { _, _ -> TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.my_text_style)}

          }
    })
    .build()
```